# Does Stellaris end at a certain time?

Tags: stellaris

In Paradox's Crusader Kings 2 the game ends at a certain date. Does Stellaris have a similar date that will cause the game to end and tally up a score or am I free to slowly grow my empire over eons?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The game has no end based on time, this is why there actually are victory conditions (either control 40% of the colonizable planets or eliminate all other independent empires).

Triggering one of those conditions (either by you or another empire) will show an end of game screen with scores, but you are allowed to continue playing.

It makes sense for Stellaris to be this way, as it is unfettered by the historical constraints of other paradox games.

Comment: Also, they're planning to add more victory conditions in future updates-hopefully ones that will be less conquest-based.

Comment: There is an end date which defaults to 2500 and a score screen will pop up on that year. But the answer is correct because technically the game doesn't end. You can play on, handle your crisis, earn achievements etc like nothing happened after closing it.